# How to move an object drawn using BezierPath in objective C using touchMoves event

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on an iPhone app in which I have to `draw` a mask and move it using touch events. I have 4 points in the mask and I have to change the size of the object by changing the position of the points.

I have drawn the main part using quadratic curves but now when I update the position of my points and a touch move event is raised, the shape of my object becomes very odd.

Please help me, I have also read about fine transform on iPhone developers forum but I'm not sure if whether I need to use it or not, because just I'm simply redrawing the object using new calculated points.

HERE IS SAMPLE CODE
this is the code for drawing point and working fine

```
        p_L.x=20.5;
        p_L.y=30.5;// corner  points
        p_T_M.y=10.5;
        p_T_M.x=60.5;
        p_R.x=100.5;
        p_R.y=30.5;

        p_L_c.x=p_L.x; control points 
        p_L_c.y=p_T_M.y;
        p_R_c.x=p_R.x;
        p_R_c.y=p_T_M.y;
        p_L_c2.x=(p_R.x-p_L.x/2);
        p_L_c2.y=p_R.y+30;


    }//// Bezier Drawing

    bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + p_L.x, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + p_L.y)];
    [bezierPath addQuadCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) +  p_T_M.x, CGRectGetMinY(frame) +  p_T_M.y) controlPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + p_L_c.x, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + p_L_c.y)];

    [bezierPath addQuadCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) +  p_R.x, CGRectGetMinY(frame) +  p_R.y) controlPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + p_R_c.x, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + p_R_c.y)];

    [bezierPath addQuadCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) +  p_L.x, CGRectGetMinY(frame) +  p_L.y) controlPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + p_L_c2.x, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + p_L_c2.y)];
    [bezierPath closePath];
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
```

problem is here in touch move event when i want to move the object ......

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point=[touch locationInView:self.displayImage];




            if( [[self tapTargetForPath:bezierPath] containsPoint:point]&& move_check==TRUE )
            {
                _displayImage.image=image_TEMP;
                CGPoint diff=CGPointMake(point.x-initial_point.x, point.y-initial_point.y);


                p_L.x=(p_L.x)+diff.x;
                p_L.y=(p_L.y)+diff.y;
                p_T_M.x=(p_T_M.x)+diff.x;
                p_T_M.y=(p_T_M.x)+diff.y;

                p_R.x= (p_R.x)+diff.x;
                p_R.y= (p_R.x)+diff.y;

                p_L_c.x=p_L_c.x+diff.x;
                p_L_c.y=p_L_c.y+diff.y;
                p_R_c.x=p_R_c.x+diff.x;
                p_R_c.y=p_R_c.y+diff.y;
                p_L_c2.x=p_L_c2.x+diff.x;
                p_L_c2.y=p_L_c2.y+diff.x;

                initial_point=point;
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_displayImage.frame.size);
                [image_TEMP drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, _displayImage.frame.size.width, _displayImage.frame.size.height)];

                CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
                CGRect frame = self.displayImage.bounds;
                bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
                [bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + p_L.x, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + p_L.y)];
                [bezierPath addQuadCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) +  p_T_M.x, CGRectGetMinY(frame) +  p_T_M.y) controlPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + p_L_c.x, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + p_L_c.y)];

                [bezierPath addQuadCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) +  p_R.x, CGRectGetMinY(frame) +  p_R.y) controlPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + p_R_c.x, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + p_R_c.y)];

                [bezierPath addQuadCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) +  p_L.x, CGRectGetMinY(frame) +  p_L.y) controlPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + p_L_c2.x, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + p_L_c2.y)];
                [bezierPath closePath];
                CGContextSaveGState(context);

                _displayImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                [_displayImage setImage:_displayImage.image];
            }

        }
```

Plz help me if someone have any idea how to do it.

what i wnt to do is basically in this link ....
http://www.taaz.com/virtual-makeover#piano=red&tab=lipstick

Comment: You should provide sample code to be able to help in a meaningful way.

Comment: here is my sample code ....

Comment: Thanx for help i got my solution after 2 days on my own.

Comment: Hello, you should add your solution and auto-accept your own answer as correct. Try to explain why it solves the problem, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i was using bezier path for 3 point to extract a an ROI in my image and i have to move this roi with touch event and also i have to adjust my point using touch in real time so when was my region it changed position of point also and there relative distance so it destroyed  the shap of the path and the problem was , In xcode bezier path requires a reference point which we call starting point or origin,and all other points and control points of curves also dependes upon this reference when someone wants to move a poth over image then just take yor refernce point do changing in it and set other points with respect to your reference point like

pointB.x=2*contsant+origin point.x;
pointB.y=2*contsant+origin point.y;

when all your points depends upon origin point you can move your path and calculate position of other points by calculating new position of al other points using there old position and old and new positions of origin point.
This is my solution i searched over stack overflow and Google it many people have this problem to move path over image using touch but nobody answered it clearly.They suggest much difficult and complex ways to check the position of touch is either inside or outside the path and all talking about tangents and curves to calculate in order to move path over image i think this is possible in a simple way as i did and it works well for me.